# Python3: Kill main thread when assert on another thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, assert, python-multithreading

Please see this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import time


def asserter():
    time.sleep(3)
    assert False


threading.Thread(target=asserter).start()

while True:
    print('Main')
    time.sleep(1)
```

I need the main loop to die when the assertion is launched. How should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to catch any threaded exceptions in the thread itself. You can then communicate that result back to the main thread somehow. Here's a minimal example that uses a shared flag object to indicate that thread has crashed. The main loop can then simply wait for that flag to change.

```
import threading
import time

class Flag:
    ended = False

def asserter(flag):
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        assert False
    except AssertionError:
        flag.ended = True


thread = threading.Thread(target=asserter, args=(Flag,))
thread.start()

while not Flag.ended:
    print('Main')
    time.sleep(1)
print('done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to 101 I've modified my code to:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import threading
import time


class Flag:
    exception = None


def asserter(flag):
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        assert False
    except Exception as e:
        flag.exception = e


threading.Thread(target=asserter, args=(Flag,)).start()

while not Flag.exception:
    print('Main')
    time.sleep(1)
raise Flag.exception
```

Now I can terminate the main program and see what happened